# quantStrat won't recognize column names

Tags: r, quantmod, algorithmic-trading, quantstrat

I wrote the following codes and got an error message when apply the strategy:

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Close' not found

sounds like the strategy can not find column "Close" price,
while the last line of code "head(mktdata)" clearly gives XLB.Close as column name of Close.
by the way, I intentionally left out the add.indicator() function which is not needed.
could anyone help? thanks
last line of code output has XLB.Close as column name:

```
head(mktdata)    
           XLB.Open XLB.High  XLB.Low XLB.Close XLB.Volume XLB.Adjusted    
2010-01-04 30.66197 31.06374 30.54327  31.06374    8287681        30.31
```

the strategy codes using quantstrat:

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
library(quantstrat)
startDate <- '2010-01-01'  # start of data    
endDate <-  '2013-07-31'   # end of data    
symbols = c("XLF", "XLP", "XLE", "XLY", "XLV", "XLI", "XLB", "XLK", "XLU")    
Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")       # set time zone

getSymbols(symbols, src='yahoo', index.class=c("POSIXt","POSIXct"),    
           from=startDate, to=endDate, adjust=TRUE)    

initDate <- '2009-12-31'   
initEq <- 1e6   
currency("USD")  
stock(symbols, currency="USD",multiplier=1)   
head(XLB)   
Lowcut1<-1.001   
Lowcut2<-1.002   

rm.strat("multiINTRO") # remove portfolio, account, orderbook if re-run    
initPortf(name="multiINTRO", symbols, initDate=initDate)    
initAcct(name="multiINTRO", portfolios="multiINTRO",
         initDate=initDate, initEq=initEq)    
initOrders(portfolio="multiINTRO", initDate=initDate)    


strategy("multiINTRO", store=TRUE)    
summary(getStrategy("multiINTRO"))    

add.signal("multiINTRO", name="sigFormula",
           arguments=list(columns=c("Close","Low"),
                          formula="(Close > Lowcut1*Low) & (Close< Lowcut2*Low)",
                          cross=FALSE),store=TRUE,env=globalenv(),
           label="longLowenter") ##Long entry


add.rule("multiINTRO", name="ruleSignal", 
         arguments=list(sigcol="longLowenter", sigval=TRUE, orderqty=100,
                        ordertype="market", orderside="long"), type="enter") ## Long enter


out<-try(applyStrategy("multiINTRO",portfolios="multiINTRO"))    
head(mktdata)
```

Answer (score 2):

`head(mktdata)` clearly gives `"XLB.Close"` as column name, and `"XLB.Close" != "Close"`.  Use quantmod's `Cl` and `Lo` column extractors on market data to get the columns you want.

Also, your `formula` argument is wrong because it's character string, not a formula. Your strategy runs for me if I change your `add.signal` call to:

```
add.signal("multiINTRO", name="sigFormula",
  arguments=list(formula=longLowenter ~ Cl(mktdata) > Lowcut1*Lo(mktdata) & Cl(mktdata)< Lowcut2*Lo(mktdata), cross=FALSE), store=TRUE, env=globalenv(),
  label="longLowenter") ##Long entry
```